# Update Functions Version on Azure

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I develop Azure Functions in Visual Studio 2019. Function are version 3 (~3). *local.settings.json" contains this:

```
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION": "~3",
```

My already deployed function is running version 3. It's up and running. VS still complains:

[image]

If I accept the value is set to ~1 (runtime not running for obvious reasons). I need manually change to ~3 after deployment.

[image]

If I don't accept an error occurs (reproduceable):

> Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

I can workaround, but at least it's annoying and I'd like to understand where the settings might come from that cause the issue.

Comment: Can my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. Just want to add that in my case the version information was missing entirely. it seems that v1 is the fallback. So in case it's missing just add this:

`<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your project is `v1` version, you can check it in `*.csproj` file:

[image]

If the created function version is `v1`, specifying `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME_VERSION` in the `local.settings.json` file will not work.

**Solution:**

Just re-create a `v3` version of the function locally and redeploy it.

The `*.csproj` file of the function of the v3 version is like this:

[image]

If you have any other problems, please let me know!